# Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, onclick

I had some issue with my code earlier today. Whenever the DOM loads or when i click the button in question, an error 'Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.' is logged into the console.

I really don't get cause the onClick *actually* is function but i get that error message.

```
//Header.jsx
function Header(onMetric, toggleMetric) {
    const toggleStyle = { display: "flex" };

    console.log(toggleMetric);  //logs an empty object to the console

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>BMI Calculator</h1>
            <div style={toggleStyle}>
                <div className="toggle-container" onClick={toggleMetric}>
                    <div className={`dialog-button ${onMetric ? "" : "disabled"}`}>
                        {onMetric ? (
                            <div style={{ height: "16px" }}></div>
                        ) : (
                            <div style={{ height: "16px" }}></div>
                        )}
                    </div>
```

Here is the App.js component:

```
//App.js

function App() {
    const [onMetric, setOnMetric] = useState(true);

    const toggleMetric = () => {
        setOnMetric(!onMetric);
    };

    return (
            <div className="container">
                <Header onMetric={onMetric} toggleMetric={toggleMetric} />
```

Also, refactoring the same exact code and putting the Toggle logic in another component of its own doesn't return that error. I may as well use that, but I'd like to know why the error is thrown in the first place, teachable moment and all.

```
//ToggleButton.jsx
function ToggleButton({ toggleMetric, onMetric }) {
    const toggleStyle = { display: "flex" };

    console.log(toggleMetric); //logs the actual function from App.js to the console

    return (
        <div className="container" style={toggleStyle}>
            <div className="toggle-container" onClick={toggleMetric}>
                <div className={`dialog-button ${onMetric ? "" : "disabled"}`}>
                    {onMetric ? (
                        <div style={{ height: "16px" }}></div>
                    ) : (
                        <div style={{ height: "16px" }}></div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the `Header` function as taking 2 arguments - but it's a React component, whose props all exist in the first argument, which is an object. This:

```
function Header(onMetric, toggleMetric) {
```

needs to be:

```
function Header({ onMetric, toggleMetric }) {
```

Comment: Thanks. really can't believe i forgot to destructure. you'd think it was an obvious error.